# Why does my PHP string comparison fail?

Tags: php

I have the following snippet of code

```
if ($summary == "CFD funding Interest Paid" ||
    $summary == "Commissions" ||
    $summary == "Closing trades") {
    print $summary.",".$date.",".$reference.",".$description.",".$amount."<br>";  
}
else {
    print $summary."*<br>";
}
```

It outputs the following

```
Commissions*
Commissions*
Closing trades*
Commissions*
Closing trades*
```

How come the strings do not appear to be matching?

Comment: What does $summary look like?

Comment: Have checked for hidden characters (new line and stuff) and case sensitivity?

Comment: I tried your code setting $summary="Commissions" and it worked correctly. Can you post the missing code before?

Answer (score 9):

Perhaps you have leading whitespace?
You could trim() that away to see if it helps?

Answer (score 7):

Use the `strcmp(str1, str2)` function instead.

Comment: + 1Upvote. I had two literally identical strings, 6 chars long - and it continued to fail.

 - "demo 2" retreived from URL decoded  $_GET.
 - "demo 2" retreived from the name of an array element.

Equality failed, however `strcmp` worked.

Comment: +1, I was comparing result of $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] to string literals. With a PUT request, `==` failed. `strcmp` worked.

Answer (score 6):

Add [`trim()`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php) before the `if ()`, it removes unvisible chars like whitespace...

```
$summary = trim($summary);
if ($summary == "CF...
```