# Using PHP function in_array with array from foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays

I am writing some values into an array from a comma separated text file like this...

```
$tokenFile  = "tokens.txt";
$tokenSet = file_get_contents($tokenFile);
$tokenValues = explode(',', $tokenSet);   

foreach($tokenValues as $value) {
        $tokens[] = "$value";
    };
```

And I get this with `print_r($tokens);`

```
Array ( [0] => token1 [1] => token2 [2] => token3 )
```

This is all good and exactly what I want, I think, but then if I use `in_array` to check for one of those values I am not getting the results I want.

```
if (in_array('token2', $tokens)) {
    echo "token found!";
};
```

If I create my `$tokens` array like below instead it works fine.

```
$tokens = array('token1', 'token2', 'token3')
```

And once again with `print_r($tokens)` I get..

```
Array ( [0] => token1 [1] => token2 [2] => token3 )
```

Both arrays appear exactly the same. What am I missing.

**Update** So the arrays are different

with var_dump I get the following array from the foreach loop

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "token1"
  [1]=>
  string(8) "token2"
  [2]=>
  string(8) "token3"
  }
```

And I get the this from the other array.

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "token1"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "token2"
  [2]=>
  string(6) "token3"
  }
```

Comment: Both Arrays are not same. One is single dimensional and other is Multidimensional. Use foreach loop.

Comment: do (with your array from the file)`var_dump($tokens);` Right click -> view source code and show us what you get there

Comment: See the difference: `string(8) "token3"` and `string(6) "token3"`

Comment: @Rizer123 Okay I updated my question above

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does my PHP string comparison fail?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028280/why-does-my-php-string-comparison-fail)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you forgot about spaces or \n \r symbols. Try to use `var_dump()` instead of `print_r` to see the difference in strings. And don't forget to use `trim()` function to remove extra symbols on both ends of a string.

```
$tokenFile  = "tokens.txt";
$tokenSet = file_get_contents($tokenFile);
$tokenValues = explode(',', $tokenSet);   

foreach($tokenValues as $value) {
    $tokens[] = trim($value);
};
var_dump($tokens);
```

Another way to get values is to use regular expressions.

Comment: Why do you know that there are still spaces? Did you saw the output of `var_dump()` from OP?

Comment: Thats the only way to have the same `print_r` output and different `in_array` behaviour for strings, that doesn't contain spaces in the middle.

Comment: Ah okay and what would be about html tags? You don't see them neither in `print_r()` nor in `var_dump()`

Comment: @shukshin Bingo! That was it.  Works perfectly now. Thanks.

Comment: Please, colleagues, don't downvote my old dummy questions 
@Rizier123, that's easy: he stores tokens, not html.